# What does it mean if an edit is attributed to Community?

Tags: discussion, editing, community-user

[This question on the Euler beta function](https://physics.stackexchange.com/posts/70051/revisions) shows a number of edits 'suggested' by Community. What exactly does this mean? Who made the edit/edit suggestions? Why is their name not displayed? If it is possible to anonymously suggest edits, how is this done?

Comment: Open the site while not logged in (Chrome Incognito or IE InPrivate mode works too), there's an "improve this answer/question" button

Comment: In this instance, BTW, that is likely the OP who has lost contact with the unregistered posting account. Judging from the style, it may well be a user we've had to suspend a time or two who has taken to often (always?) using throwaway accounts coming through a big proxy farm.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I asked this question in a comment not too long ago and QMechanic responded...

It means it's an edit suggested anonymously by somebody not logged in or not signed up for the site. If you log out and go to any question/answer, you can suggest edits.